Calling a python script with a parameter
I am very new to python and having problem in doing a probably very basic thing. I have a python script script1.py which calculates some quantity and this quantity depends on the value of a variable B initialised inside the script. I have another script script2.py which does some calculations and returns a value. I want to pass this value as the value of the variable B in script1. How can I do this. In particular

How do  I modify script1 such that it takes a input and uses this input for B?
How do I pass the value from script2  to script1?

I am not sure how to go about it. Any help will be appreciated

I assume you have script1.py and script2.py in the same folder.
script1.py
def calc_something(value01):
    return value01+100

script2.py
import script1 

input01=200
print(script1.calc_something(input01))

command py script2.py
and the result will be 300

Depending on the context there are a few ways to do what you want to do. The above poster provided the most obvious, with the import function basically allowing you to call your script1 function as if it was in script2.
Just in case you are wanting to run this from the command line, then you can also using sys:
import sys
sys.argv  #this will return a list of the arguments from the command line

